# Database of names similar to bibliography in arabic

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, arabic, database

The example is with the particular case of Arabic, but could be extended to a more general case.

When writing academic papers containing Arabic names, each journal has a particular transliteration system. I would like to know if I could build my database of names with different romanizations for each name (some of them require diacritics, others don't) and then use the one I need for each journal. It would work similar to a bibliographic database :

```
@name{tusi,
arabicname = {{محمد بن محمد بن الحسن ,{طوسی‎},
latinname = {Nasir al-Din Tusi}
translit1 = {{Ṭūsī}, Naṣīr al-Dīn Muḥammad ibn Muḥammad},
translit2 = {Ṭusi}, Nasir al-Din Muhammad ibn Muhammad},
translit3 = {another one},
....}
```

Then, I would "cite" them and choose the transliteration I want for each document. I could choose also the format: transliteration (Arabic name), or transliteration (Arabic name as footnote).

Comment: The solution can be found here:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196399/biblatex-biber-problems-with-texlive-2014-no-problems-2013